# Visual Studio Code unable to debug Electron

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, electron

I am using Electron on Visual Studio Code on Windows 8. I am new to Electron.
I used the [electron-quick-start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) which works in Visual Studio Code when running it with the VS Code terminal. But when I try to debug the code I get the following error:

```
Debugger listening on [::]:46522
e:\Projects\BT\electron-quick-start\main.js:40
app.on('ready', createWindow)
   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (e:\Projects\BT\electron-quick-start\main.js:40:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Timeout.Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:604:10)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)
```

The error occurs when the debugger reaches the following line in main.js:

```
// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

I exactly use the code in [electron-quick-start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start). That means for package.json:

```
{
  "name": "electron-quick-start",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A minimal Electron application",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start",
  "keywords": [
    "Electron",
    "quick",
    "start",
    "tutorial",
    "demo"
  ],
  "author": "GitHub",
  "license": "CC0-1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "~1.6.2"
  }
}
```

What have I to do to can debug this code in Visual Studio Code

Comment: As I said it does work when I run it with terminal: inside and outside VSCode. Problem is when trying to debug it with VSCode

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same commands on both terminals? What terminals are you using? cmd? Powershell? WSL?

Comment: Yes. I am using cmd in Windows 8 when calling it outside VS Code and in VS Code I use the integrated terminal. For both I use the command "npm start" and it works in both of them. Problem occurs when I try to debug it

Comment: and the Integrated terminal is set to use cmd?

Comment: Yes. It is set cmd

Comment: The person who has downgraded my question should be removed from stackoverflow. Instead of answering the clear question, just downgrade the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It showed that this was a global problem that was fixed in the new update 1.17.2 of VS Code. So I don't know why some people have downgraded this question although it was a relevant question and why stackoverflow allows that, but for all the people who have had this problem, I post this answer.
After installing the new update 1.17.2 the problem was fixed. VS Code has solved that in version 1.17. [Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/debugging-recipes) are some info about the features and bug fixes (including the electron feature in VS Code).